# Relation between Services and Nodes

Tags: ros, rosservice, nodes, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a very simple question. What's the relation between services and nodes? Can we say services are functions/methods defined in a node. For example, according to this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams

when I'm running the turtlesim_node node, here is the list of active services:

/clear 
/kill 
/reset 
/rosout/get_loggers 
/rosout/set_logger_level 
/spawn 
/teleop_turtle/get_loggers 
/teleop_turtle/set_logger_level 
/turtle1/set_pen 
/turtle1/teleport_absolute 
/turtle1/teleport_relative 
/turtlesim/get_loggers 
/turtlesim/set_logger_level

The question is where are all these services defined? Where can I find their codes?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189736/relation-between-services-and-nodes/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, services are functions in a node that can be called remotely.

Therefore they are defined in the source code of the respective node.

You can find out which node is running a service by using `rosservice info SERVICE_NAME`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

services are declared in `.srv` and functionality defined in `.cpp`

refrer [.srv files](http://wiki.ros.org/srv)  for more info.

check srv folder for services declared. [turtlesim code](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/turtlesim)

in [turtle.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/c02fe2cc1f94022ddd68d1ff8e4f8c456815c011/turtlesim/src/turtle.cpp)

```
  set_pen_srv_              = nh_.advertiseService("set_pen", &Turtle::setPenCallback, this);
  teleport_relative_srv_ = nh_.advertiseService
                                      ("teleport_relative", &Turtle::teleportRelativeCallback, this);
  teleport_absolute_srv_ = nh_.advertiseService
                                      ("teleport_absolute", &Turtle::teleportAbsoluteCallback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1